Optimizing Kalman Filter's parameters
my question is how to optimize Kalman Filter's parameters? Well, everyone I asked says that I shoud do it manually by just guessing and then watching how it corellates with ground truth. Is there more practical, automatic method?

From the plot shown I would say that you should first focus on improving your model, before focussing on the gains of the parameters of the Kalman filter. Namely "badly" chosen Kalman filter parameters should only lead to higher noise present in your estimate, but your plot shows mainly a bias.
